# Asp.net MVC deserialize Kendo Grid data in the controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Application.
I have a View with a Kendo.Grid and I want to send with ajax (JSON.stringify) the data of the grid at the controller.

My problem is that my controller receives a List of string and I don't know how to deserialize the Json Data.

**CODE**

This is the object contained in the rows of the grid:

```
public class CourseDto
{
    public string CodCourse { get; set; }
    public string DesCourse { get; set; }
}
```

This is the definition of the grid in my View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CourseDto>()
    .Name("GridCourses")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.CodCourse);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DesCourse);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read("GetAllCourses", "ControllerCourses")
    )
)
```

This is the ajax call to the controller with jquery:

```
function passTheGrid() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ShowCourses")",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            courses : JSON.stringify($("#GridCourses").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data());
       },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#coursesDiv").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ShowCourses(List<string> courses)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<string> temp= new List<string>();
    foreach (var singleCourse in courses)
    {
        temp.Add(js.Deserialize<string>(singleCourse));
    }
    ...
    return PartialView("_viewCourses");
}
```

In my example I have only a cource in the grid and when I pass the data with ajax at the controller, the parameter "courses" contains this string:

```
[{"CodCourse":"PRIVSIC0102006","DesCourse":"MULTIMEDIA - PRIVACY AND SECURITY"}]
```

But I get this Error when I try to deserialize:

> Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of a matrix

**QUESTION**

How do I deserialize the JSON Data in my controller correctly?

Comment: Firstly deserialize json to your model CourseDto, then override CourseDto ToString method, so call ToString().

Comment: @Oğuzhan Soykan I try to deserialize directly in my model "CourseDto" but the deserialize give me error: "CourseDto is not supported for deserialization of a matrix."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved changing the code:

**Call Ajax**

```
function passTheGrid() {
    var o = kendo.observable({
        myCourses: $("#GridCourses").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()
    });
    var courses = JSON.stringify(o);
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ShowCourses")",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            courses : courses ,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#coursesDiv").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

The ajax call pass this data:

```
{"myCourses":[{"CodCourse":"PRIVSIC0102006","DesCourse":"MULTIMEDIA - PRIVACY AND SECURITY"}]}
```

**The controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ShowCourses(string courses)
{
    var coursesJson = JObject.Parse(courses).SelectToken("myCourses").ToString();

    var coursesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CourseDto>>(coursesJson);
    ...
    return PartialView("_viewCourses");
}
```

and the course list contains the object CourseDto.

Answer (score 0):

MVC's built in serializer should be able to do this, assuming that the JSON structure you're passing in matches the structure of `CourseDto`.

Update your controller method that accepts the Post to something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ShowCourses(List<CourseDto> courses)
{
    foreach (var singleCourse in courses)
    {
        // do something with your courses
    }
    ...
    return PartialView("_viewCourses");
}
```

Also, update your JS function that passes the data to the controller so that the `myCourses` becomes `courses` to match your controller param.

```
function passTheGrid() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ShowCourses")",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            courses : JSON.stringify($("#GridCourses").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data());
       },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#coursesDiv").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. The parameter courses is null.

Comment: sorry, i edit and correct my question. It was wrong. Even if I change the name of the parameter in the ajax call "courses" like the parameter of the controller "courses" the value in the controller is always null. I post a answer at my question few minutes ago. I found a solution.